# Android duplicate webrtc class when I use 2 library dependencies on webrtc

Tags: android, duplicates, webrtc

I got error when I use twillio and sora library.
Error:Execution failed for task ':quickstart:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.

> com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: org/webrtc/Camera1Session$2.class

I've researched and I know that 2 library extend from org.webrtc, so When android system build then I will duplicate org.web.

I spent 3 weeks for this issue, but i cannot resolve.
Any solution would be appreciate

Thank!

Comment: Can you please provide dependencies info, which helps us to identify issue.

Comment: I use:
compile 'com.twilio:video-android:1.3.6'
compile("com.github.shiguredo:sora-android-sdk:1.3.0:release@aar") {
        transitive = true
    }